# How to convert TypeScript FormData into JSON object

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript, next.js

I am experimenting with nextjs and I have a page with a form which submits to a server action.

The action receives the FormData as follows

```
FormData {
  [Symbol(state)]: [
    { name: 'firstName', value: '' },
    { name: 'lastName', value: '' },
    { name: 'primaryAddress.street', value: '' },
    { name: 'primaryAddress.city', value: '' },
    { name: 'previousAddress[0].street', value: '' },
    { name: 'previousAddress[0].city', value: '' },
    { name: 'previousAddress[1].street', value: '' },
    { name: 'previousAddress[1].city', value: '' }
  ]
}
```

Is there a library I can use which would convert that into a json object, something similar to the following

```
{
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  primaryAddress: {street: '', city: ''}
  previousAddresses: [
    {street: '', city: ''},
    {street: '', city: ''}
  ]
}
```

Looking online there does not seem to be any clear solution.

The only solution I can think of is to use a client component and send a custom json request to an api route rather than using the server component.

Comment: can you show what you already try ?